Python and Pip Versions
I had an old Python version on one MacBook, and I'm used to having updated stuff on another MacBook, so I brew install python on the first one.
Then, I got this when checking:
$ python3 --version
Python 3.12.3
$ pip --version
pip 23.3 from /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)

Is this normal? Or should my pip follow the same Python version?

No worries, pip and Python are two different things.

Related: Dealing with multiple Python versions and PIP? (answers cover best practice)

Does this effectively answer your question? Pip suddenly using wrong version of Python. It's a bit of a different situation, but the answer seems 95% applicable to this situation.

Or this? PIP3 associated with the wrong python version

If all this feels ambiguous to you, just pip3.12 install instead of pip install.

It's abundantly clearly from any outstanding example of other people checking the Pip version (such as in How to know the version of pip itself, that it's a completely different number from the corresponding Python. - oh, I see, this is about the Python version reported by Pip vs the python command.

@wjandrea as nice as it would be to have a canonical to explain how python and pip installations correlate, it's hard to phrase a question that would actually contain the necessary information and let people present it directly.

No worries at all about this. Pip is a simple script which fetches package from pypi and runs setup.py on it (in very simple terms of how it works).
If you create new venv and if you try to run pip3/pip install, you will see the prompt showing that you may have to update your pip. It will also show you the information about how you can do it:
python3 -m pip install –upgrade pip


Why it is bad to have an old pip installed? I observed some wheel problems. Seems like there were some improvements and, also, maybe it also uses some older dependencies to build the things.
